# Jackson - parse nested array of arrays

Tags: java, json, jackson

There is this JSON string:

```json
{
  "status": 200,
  "result": [
    [
      123,
      "FOO",
      "BAR",
      456
    ],
    [
      123,
      "FOO",
      "BAR",
      456
    ],
  ]
}
```

and I need to parse this object and get `status` field and all arrays in `result` JSON property. (There could be 1...n of these arrays.)

I use this DTO:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TestDto {
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private Integer status;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

to parse JSON but I have no idea how to parse the `result` array.

Is it possible to accomplish it with such simple DTO file or do I need to create custom `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer`?

Comment: String[][] result;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anything 2-dimensional.

Both:

```
private Object[][] result;
```

and

```
private List<List<Object>> result;
```

can do the job.

Comment: I had no idea it's so simple, sometimes one overcomplicates a simple solution :-)